# NSArray's mutableCopy - performance concerns

Tags: objective-c, performance, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have the following concern. I have a piece of code where I care about performance a lot (to be honest, I'm trying to make it as much optimized as possible).

I have something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [someInstance getArray];
if (something) {
   NSMutableArray *marray = [array mutableCopy];
   [marray removeObject:someObject];
   [marray insertObject:someObject atIndex:0];

   array = marray;
}
```

The goal is to move `someObject` to the beginning of the array - quite simple. However, the point is elsewhere. Method `[someInstance getArray]` returns `NSArray *`, but internally it also uses `NSMutableArray`:

```
- (NSArray *)getArray {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    // do some stuff here
    return array;
}
```

I'm trying to keep all my interfaces returning immutable collections. But in the above case I'm thinking of creating an exception from that rule since I care a lot about performance in this piece of code. So I can change the `getArray` method to the following:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getArray {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    // do some stuff here
    return array;
}
```

and then change my ultra-efficient code as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [someInstance getArray];
if (something) {
   [array removeObject:someObject];
   [array insertObject:someObject atIndex:0];
}
```

Does above change make any sense in the terms of performance?

Comment: You tell us. Use Instruments and test it.

Comment: If Instruments were not hanging, I would not ask :)

Comment: You're "optimizing" without being able to measure? Don't do that. Nothing good can come of it.

Comment: Anyone can answer instead of asking why do I ask? Honestly, I don't want to write a full story about the problems I'm facing with Instruments right now. Most of the work I already did with Instruments but now they don't work (don't know why) and this is the last non-obvious concern I have. So that's why I ask.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to the problems you seem to be having with Instruments. My point was, suppose you make the changes I suggest (or others). How would you know if it improved matters?

Comment: I will know if I fix my Instruments :) Probably I need to reinstall Xcode. I was just going through the code and spot this piece of code so instead of fighting with broken instruments, I decided to ask here in hope that someone already know the answer since this is not a question "how to refactor this algorithm to work faster" but rather about Foundation mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` supports copy-on-write. From the [Foundation Release Notes for macOS 10.13 and iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html):

#### Collection Copy-on-Write

> NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSSet now implement “copy on write” (CoW),
>   which means that a copy of a mutable instance will often not be a full
>   copy, but a much cheaper, O(1) operation. A full copy is done only
>   when either one of the objects (the original or the copy) is mutated
>   down the line.
>
> Please see [WWDC 2017 session 244 “Efficient Interactions with
>   Frameworks”](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/244/) for more info on this.

What that means is that copying the array is cheap. Modifying it while the original is still around, though, is potentially expensive.

So, you could do this:

```
if (something) {
   NSMutableArray *marray = [array mutableCopy];
   array = nil;
   [marray removeObject:someObject];
   [marray insertObject:someObject atIndex:0];
   array = [marray copy];
}
```

The copy results in two objects sharing a backing store. By clearing `array` before mutating `marray`, the original should be released leaving only one. Then, the mutations don't need to copy it because it's no longer shared.

Also, as recommended in that WWDC video, when you have a method that creates an array that's mutable while you set it up, but that you want to return as immutable, you can and should return a copy instead of just a direct pointer:

```
- (NSArray *)getArray {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    // do some stuff here
    return [array copy];
}
```

That's safer and still cheap.

Comment: Thank you! Finally constructive answer :) I was not aware of how it works.

Comment: Just of curiosity: why returning a copy of mutable array where immutable is expected is safer? If this is explained in the video, please ignore me.

Comment: Well, I guess it's not safer for a method like `-getArray` here, which is making a new mutable array and forgetting about it after it returns. It's safer in the general case of methods returning an immutable-typed pointer to a mutable collection that may be referenced elsewhere.

Comment: That makes sense. That's why I didn't see any benefit of safety in my particular case. Anyway, thanks @ken-thomases for your explanation!